# I'm editing my .bashrc file to backup history but it doesn't work as expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to write this code for my `.bashrc` file to backup my `.bash_history` but I can't figure out the ending, this is the code that doesn't work:

```
if [ $name -ot "$name-$minus$old" ]
then
    printf "%s\n" ".bash_history will be cleared soon, backing up....!"
    cp ~/.bash_history "$new_name"
fi
```

**How do I prevent it from creating a new file everytime I start the `shell/terminal` and the `(wc -l < ~/.bash_history) >= 99000` condition is met?**

The code is supposed to do this:

Backup my `.bash_history` file if it is 1000 lines or less from the defined size of `HISTSIZE=100000` and `HISTFILESIZE=100000` lines, then backup the file.

1. Check if `.bash_history` is 99000 lines or more.
2. Check if `~/.bash_history.old` exists, if it doesn't use that filename.
3. Increment `i` one digit larger than is already used by filenames.(filename-4.old)
4. Check if there are more than 20 files already backed up and warn if it is.
5. Set the new filename into a variable.
6. Check if the last file with a digit in it's filename is older than the original.
7. `cp` the file to `new_name`

### Here is the code:

```
if (( $(wc -l < ~/.bash_history) >= 99000 ))
then
    name=~/.bash_history
    old=.old
    if [[ ! -e ~/.bash_history.old ]]
    then
       printf "%s\n" ".bash_history will be cleared soon, backing up....!"
       cp $name ~/.bash_history.old
    else
        i=0
        if [[ -e $name$old ]]
        then
            while [[ -e "$name-$i$old" ]]
            do
                let i++
            done
        fi
        if [[ "$i" -ge 20 ]]
        then
            printf "%s\n" "You need to arhive your history files they are mounting up!!!"
        fi
        new_name=$name-$i$old
        minus=$(( i - 1 ))
        if [ $name -ot "$name-$minus$old" ]
        then
            printf "%s\n" ".bash_history will be cleared soon, backing up....!"
            cp ~/.bash_history "$new_name"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

This is the result from `shellcheck.net`:

```
Line 16:
    let i++
    ^-- SC2219: Instead of 'let expr', prefer (( expr )) .
```

### **I'm learning but as of now I'm a really crappy programmer. This is what I've come up with, please give me feedback and advice:**

```
########################333############# backup history
if (( $(wc -l < ~/.bash_history) <= 99900 ))
then
    name=~/.bash_history
    old=.old
    if [[ ! -e "$name""$old" ]]
    then
        printf "%s\n" "##################################################" ".bash_history will be cleared soon, backing up....!" "##################################################"
        cp "$name" "$name""$old"
    else
        incre=0
        if [[ -e "$name""$old" ]]
        then
            while [[ -e "$name"-"$incre""$old" ]]
            do
                (( incre++ ))
            done
        fi
        if [[ "$incre" -ge 20 ]]
        then
            printf "%s\n" "********************************************************" "You need to arhive your history files they are mounting up!!!" "**************************************************************"
        fi
        # collect both times in seconds-since-the-epoch
        twelve_days_ago=$(date -d 'now - 12 days' +%s)
        file_time=$(date -r "$name" +%s)
        new_name="$name"-"$incre""$old"
        increMinusOne=$(( incre - 1 ))
        #answer=""
        #printf "%s\n" "Do you want to backup 'bash_history' now?"
        #read -r answer
        #if [[ "$answer" == "y" ]] || [[ "$answer" == "Y" ]] 
        #minus=$(( i - 1 ))
        if [ -e "$name-$increMinusOne$old" ]
        then
            if [ $name -ot "$name-$increMinusOne$old" ]
            then
                printf "%s\n" "##################################################" ".bash_history will be cleared soon, backing up....!" "##################################################"
                cp "$name" "$name-$increMinusOne$old"
            fi    
        elif [ -e "new_name" ]
        then
            new_time=$(date -r "$new_name" +%s)
            if [ "$name" -nt "$new_name" ] &&  (( $(wc -l < "$name") > $(wc -l < "$new_name")  ))
            then
                printf "%s\n" "##################################################" ".bash_history will be cleared soon, backing up....!" "##################################################"
                cp "$name" "$new_name"
            # ...and then just use integer math:
            elif (( new_time <= twelve_days_ago ))
            then
                echo "$new_name is older than 12 days"
                printf "%s\n" "##################################################" ".bash_history will be cleared soon, backing up....!" "##################################################"
                cp "$name" "$new_name"
            fi
        else
            printf "%s\n" "##################################################" ".bash_history will be cleared soon, backing up....!" "##################################################"
            cp "$name" "$new_name"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Comment: `Check if there are more than 20 files already backed up and warn if it is.` - that's easier done. Just `find . - type f -name "$name-*"` the files. Remember to  `| sort`. Then just `wc -l` -> if the count is greater then 20, then remove the first 20 `tail -n+21` and remove all the rest. Ie. `if (( $(find . -type f -name "$name-*" | wc -l)) >= 20 )); then find . type f -name "$name-*" | sort -n | tail -n +21 | xargs rm; fi`

Comment: no no files in the directory

Comment: We can't debug your code and fix it for you.